# How to Create symlinks from a list in a file

Tags: php

How do I create symlinks from a list in a file using PHP and a browser?

Someone gave me the remarkably simple answer of using from console `>$ bash name-of-file.ext` but I want a solution using PHP.

Comment: It's completely fine to ask a question and answer it yourself if it can be helpful for other users. But when you do, you still need to write the question properly (full explanation of what you're trying to do, the issue, example data, expected result etc.) so future visitors actually knows what the real issue is. It also makes it easier to search for the issue.

Comment: The original post has been edited to not explain that I was presenting an answer to a question. SO whjat is the reasopn for the down vote?

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but it's most likely because the question is of poor quality (read my first comment).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I'm assume that you saw the original post before it was amended by the "Principle" editor. It stated that I had asked the question here and was given the rally simple answer (stated above) but that the person who responded suggested that I remove the question (which I did) and now had found a PHP web browser solution posted as the answer. I'm sure I'm not the only idiot online who sometimes doesn't not know really simple solutions. As a writer and editor for 40 years, I still am unaware of many things grammatical.

Comment: If you've been a writer and editor for 40 years, I can assume that you are good at reading so again, read my first comment _properly_. I said that it's _ok_ to ask and answer yourself. _However_, the question _still_ needs to include (as stated above) _"(full explanation of what you're trying to do, the issue, example data, expected result etc.)"_. The content that was removed from this question didn't have _anything_ to do with your actual issue. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We also haven't seen your previous question so we have no idea what it looked like, who told you to do what or why and honestly, we don't care. Every question has to be able to stand on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem I was having was when the application was loaded to my virtual host's server. I didn't want to give them two lists totaling 50 symlinks and so searched to find the PHP solution from the web browser. I found the simple `symlink($target,$link);` to make one link and still didn't want to do it one-at-a-time.

So I went for a loop through the CSV I created from replacing the white space between targets and links with commas. Here's the resulting code:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('makesymlinks.txt'));
array_shift($csv);
foreach($csv as $row =>$data)
{
    $target = $data[0];
    $link = $data[1];
    //echo "{$target} {$link}<br>";
    symlink($target,$link);
}
```

The `array_shift()` is only necessary to remove the headings I used in the CSV to help keep my bearings and can be removed if not needed. You can `echo` the output to see if it works before usage. Also, you can catch errors if you choose to.